# Google pub/sub push subscriber error "The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to write a push based subscriber for Google Cloud pub/sub

My code looks like this

```
try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient.create(subscriptionAdminSettings)) {
  ProjectSubscriptionName name = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(PROJECT, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);
  ProjectTopicName topic = ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT, TOPIC_NAME);
  PushConfig pushConfig = PushConfig.newBuilder().setPushEndpoint(PUSH_ENDPOINT).build();
  int ackDeadlineSeconds = 5;
  Subscription subscription = subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(name, topic, pushConfig, ackDeadlineSeconds);
}
```

However, I get this error at runtime

```
The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project 
(url="https://...", project_id="8xxxxxxxxx5").
```

**Where do I need to register this url?** Somewhere in project, or with topic?

<sub>Found some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-pubsub-discuss/QSPvRdgizvQ) but seems slightly dated as some of those links are redirecting to other docs now.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To prevent unwelcome traffic, Cloud Pub/Sub requires you to verify your ownership of the push endpoint. Please follow the steps at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#domain_ownership_validation to verify ownership of your push endpoint.

Comment: i have verified my ownership. Still facing this issue.

Comment: Can you please edit the question thread to indicate how you verified ownership in your code? This Stackoverflow thread might also help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51413501/cloud-pub-sub-http-url-is-not-registered-even-after-domain-is-registered